# Solspace Freeform - Change "submit" button to "next"

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm building out multi-page forms using composer. And having a submit button at the bottom of page 1 (of 5) is weird.

Can I change the text for the next/previous buttons on pages using the freeform render tag?

I'd prefer that only the last page of the form have the submit button, and all the other pages have buttons that say "Previous" and/or "Next."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the button that you are adding while making the form, it allows you to change the text to whatever you want it to say. Is that not what you are wanting to do?

Comment: yeah, it's on the right bar. and my form was long enough that i didn't see the sidebar change when I clicked the field. idiot mistake.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!